# What are the least crowded times to visit the Aquarium in Brooklyn, NYC?

Tags: planning, sightseeing, new-york-city

If having less crowds is an important consideration, when is the best time to visit Brooklyn Aquarium?

(which times of year - preferably summer, which days of week, which times of day).

Comment: If you search '<place> opening hours' in Google (unquoted), there's often a schematic on the right side that shows generally how busy a place is. Your best bet is probably a weekday (Tuesday or Thursday) and get there right when they open. Attendance appears to taper off in the last open hour of the day too.

Answer (score 4):

What mkennedy said in his comment is right.

[This google search](https://www.google.be/search?q=Brooklyn%20Aquarium&oq=Brooklyn%20Aquarium&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:2&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=40648836,-73982722,8671&tbm=lcl&ved=0ahUKEwiLuIK6lsvNAhXmAMAKHY_6ANYQvS4IODAA&rlfi=hd:;si:5041021370269948892#rlfi=hd:;si:5041021370269948892) shows you how busy they think it will be over the course of the day.

[image: Monday]
[image: Tuesday]
[image: Wednesday]
[image: Thursday]
[image: Friday]
[image: Saturday]
[image: Sunday]

Looks like trough the week it's pretty even.

I hope it is the aquarium you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a summary of how busy it is each day of the week and quietest periods, and that would make your answer more useful

Comment: I completely agree with @Berwyn, to make this answer useful, could you please include a summary both over weekdays and time of the day? Otherwise this answer is no more useful than the mentioned comment right now.

Comment: Good idea guys, let me change that!